How to load SVG in Flutter web wasm?
I'm currently developing a Flutter web application with the latest Flutter version 3.22.2 and targeting WebAssembly (WASM). I need to render SVG images without relying on HTML or any packages that depend on HTML due to the constraints imposed by WASM.
I've tried using the flutter_svg package, but it seems to rely on HTML, which isn't compatible with the WASM setup. Here's a simplified version of my current approach:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

class SvgExample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('SVG Example'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: SvgPicture.asset(
          'assets/example.svg',
          semanticsLabel: 'Example SVG',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: SvgExample(),
  ));
}


When I run the application using the --wasm flag, I encounter issues related to HTML dependencies.
What I need help with:
Are there any Flutter packages or methods that allow rendering SVG images in a Flutter web application running with WASM without depending on HTML?
If there are no such packages available, what are the alternative approaches to achieve SVG rendering in this environment?
Any guidance or example code snippets would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I believe that this problem exists only in 3.22.2, since I can not reproduce it in 3.22.1, for example. So, first possible option – to downgrade flutter or wait for the next release, because fix is already in the main channel
If both options are not suited for you, you can use workaround.
flutter_svg uses vector_graphics under the hood.
Community provided temporary workaround for 3.22.2, here it is
And here is how you can use this workaround in your project, just add this block to your pubspec.yaml:
dependency_overrides:
  vector_graphics_compiler:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/nohli/vector_graphics
      path: packages/vector_graphics_compiler
      ref: js_interop

I tested it myself. Compilation errors are gone and I've been able to compile my sample project with 3.22.2.

That worked for me too thanks
